# How do I add an on click event listener using an argument passed to a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Here are my functions:

```
function type(message) {
    document.getElementById("body").innerHTML="<div id=\"textbox\" class=\"textbox\"></div><div id=\"oc\" class=\"option-container\"></div>"
    for (let i=1; i<9; i++) {
        document.getElementById("oc").innerHTML+="<div id=\"o"+i+"\" class=\"option\"></div>"
    }
    printLetterByLetter("textbox", message, 15)
}

function createop(text, program) {
    for (let i=1; i<9; i++) {
        if (!document.getElementById("o"+i).classList.contains("filled")) {
            document.getElementById("o"+i).classList.add("filled")
            document.getElementById("o"+i).innerText=text
            document.getElementById("o"+i).addEventListener("click", ()=> {program})
            i=9
        }
    }
}
```

The type function is always called before the createop function.

I want to run whatever the `program` argument contains when that HTML object is clicked on. The way I did it above does not work. How can I do this?

The code in its entirety can be found here: https://github.com/Fish767/Feedback-Nightmare/tree/master and the two functions above are located in the asterfix.js file which is in the js folder.

Comment: First off, you have a weird if statement... `//if this element has the filled class, add the filled class to it` just seems redundant. Second, what is program? What is it that you are passing to your function? --> Edit: Ah, it seems that I missed that you are adding it to the next element and not the current element, in response to my first point.

Comment: @ShanerM13 I am passing it different things depending on where it is called. Mostly it is calling other functions of changing some variables. an example would be `updateGUI3()`

Comment: Sry, please rewrite your question. It is *very* difficult to understand. Break it down to 1 question if possible.

Comment: @wazz I rewrote it. Hopefully it makes more sense now. Sorry.

Comment: So... what it looks like is you want to actually do something along the lines of `eval(program)`... which is not a good practice, but is a quick and dirty solution. Let me know if that is what you are looking for. Especially given the nature of the createop() function, it may be a big problem in the future to try and run any function in a string. I would be looking for a better way to implement that function instead of using eval(), which is something we can talk about if you are down.

Comment: It seems like it would be much more practical to create a class that contains "methods" for manipulating values set for each "button". And... I am a bit uncertain as to if the contents of "program" would stay the same or change using `eval(program);`, but given a new instance of some class you created, it will always be whatever function you tell it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by slightly modifying the for loop in the createop function. If we remove all the options that have no code in them, then we can recreate them and add code to the first one. The options with code have the class `filled` and we can use this to determine which options are empty.

```
function createop(text, program) {

    //used in if statement later
    let temporarycode=program


    for (let i=1; i<9; i++) {

        //This determines which options are filled. It selects all that are not
        if (!document.getElementById("o"+i).classList.contains("filled")) {


            //delete the empty option and create a new option that contains the passed arguments
            document.getElementById("o"+i).remove()
            document.getElementById("oc").innerHTML+="<div id=\"o"+i+"\" class=\"option\" onclick=\""+temporarycode+"\">"+text+"</div>"


            //this is used to determine if the option is the first one modified
            if (temporarycode===program) {


                //adds the filled class so we don't modify this with future additions
                document.getElementById("o"+i).classList.add("filled")
            }


            //replace the arguments so that each option after the first is empty
            temporarycode=""
            text=""
        }
    }
}
```

By removing each empty option and adding them again we maintain the proper number of options desired and we keep them in the proper order.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR 
You are missing parentheses to call the function. Solution code:

```
function createop(text, program) {
    for (let i=1; i<9; i++) {
        if (!document.getElementById("o"+i).classList.contains("filled")) {
            document.getElementById("o"+i).classList.add("filled")
            document.getElementById("o"+i).innerText=text
            document.getElementById("o"+i).addEventListener("click", ()=> {program()})
            i=9
        }
    }
}
```

Long answer:
By not putting the parentheses after `program`, you are just writing a serialized form of the function and then ending the line. The following program shows serialized vs called (without parens vs with).

```js
function abc() {
  return "abc";
}

console.log("Without parens: " + abc);
console.log("With parens: " + abc());
```

Edit:
You are calling the `creatop` function like this:

```
createop("Try Again","stop=true;updateGUI4();")
```

However it is not good practice to use strings and `eval()` them (what you are trying to do here will fail in strict mode)

Alternatively, you could call the function like this:

```
createop("Try Again",()=>{let stop=true;updateGUI4();})
```

which uses anonymous functions to allow the above solution to work. However, this will not change the value of the `stop` variable.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my situation. program is an argument of the createop function. When I call the createop function I pass it text to write on the option it creates and then code to run when the option is clicked. For example: `createop("Try Again","stop=true;updateGUI4();")`. Program is not a function.

Comment: @Fish767 Well, the method you are looking for then is `eval()` however eval is pretty bad practice to use. The alternative is to use anonymous functions, see my updated answer

Comment: @Fish767 I am not sure how you are expecting the `stop` variable to work in the example you wrote. Where are you expecting the scope of that variable to be changed in?

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. I figured writing a class would help to solve that problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in practice. I am going to try removing the placeholder options that the for loop made and reentering them with a new for loop. I'll let you all know if it works.

Comment: @Fish767 What about it doesn't work? I'm sure we could help but you should tell us. Could you answer my previous question about what scope the stop variable should be changed in?

Comment: @NateLevin The variable is a global variable that is used to stop the printLetterByLetter function from printing more letters to the screen. This makes each screen have individual text and ensures the text from one screen doesn't bleed over to another. That's not the issue I am having though. The event listener doesn't seem to be calling anything. I had the idea that I could just delete the HTML elements that don't have the class `Filled` and then replace them after. I am fairly sure this will work, I just have to look up one thing on google first.

Comment: @NateLevin what wasn't working was that somewhere along the line no function was added to the onclick event listener. I wasn't receiving an error or the desired response. I did find a way to make my intention work, but it isn't nearly as clean as your idea and will probably raise overall loading time by a slight amount.